# Why do we have to use the exponents for this decay probelem.

Tags: calculus

"A certain radioactive material is known to decay at a rate proportional to the amount present. If initially there is 50 milligrams of the material present and after two hours it is observed that the material has lost $10$ percent of its original mass, find ($a$) an expression for the mass of the material remaining at any time $t$"

I know the normal method would be to get the formula $y = 50e^{-kt}$ , then solve the two simultaneous equations to get $k$.

But if i use $dy = -ky\cdot dt$ with $dy$ as $0.1y$ and $dt$ as $2$, I don't get the exact same value for $k$.

I know the first method is the correct one, but, why don't I get the exact same value when i use that method?

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange.  The equation $dy=-ky\cdot dt$ works for infinitesimals

Answer (score 0):

Remember that dy is the differential on y, meaning that dy should be the difference between the initial ammount and the final amount after the two hours.